# Struggling with evaluating if statement within foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a long list of over 1000 parts, I then display a list of related parts depending on the make and model that was selected.

After selecting the parts by providing the number of items per part it get stored as `$_SESSION['var55'] = 1;`

On refresh of the page for whatever reason I want to rebuild the form but this time adding the number of items/part per part by allocating the var value to the html value parameter.

ex.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['var55']) {echo 'value="' . $_SESSION['var55'] . '"'
```

Should then provide:

```
<input id="55" name="55" value="1" style="color:blue" type="number" min="0" max="5">
```

I have tried to construct an array but then again had difficulty with selecting the correct id using the $variables.

I cant seem to populate the correct id using variables to match the `$_SESSION['var']` to the input ID while running the for eachloop that draws the info from the DB.

```
$partsQuery = "SELECT
           partID,
           partNo,
           AFN,
           partDesc,
           brand,
           partURL
                  FROM
           lu_part
                  WHERE
           makeID = $makeID AND modelID = $modelID                        
          ";  

          $parts = $db->query($partsQuery);
```

```
<?php foreach($parts->fetchAll() as $part):?>

<div class="partItemBox imagehighlight">    
<span>
<center><img class="partItems" src="<?php echo $part['partURL'];?>" alt="part">
<label style="margin:16px" for="<?php echo $part['partID']; ?>">PART NO.: <?php echo $part['partNo'];?> / <?php echo $part['AFN'];?><br>DESCRIPTION: <?php echo $part['partDesc'];?><br>BRAND: <?php echo $part['brand'];?></label>
<input id="<?php echo 'var' . $part['partID'];?>" name="<?php echo 'var' . $part['partID'];?>"
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["'var" . $part['partID' . "'"]])) {
echo 'value="' . $_SESSION['\"var\" . $part[\'partID\']'] . '"'; } else {$_SESSION[$part['partID']];} ?>
style="margin-top:0px" type="number" min="0" max="5">     
</center>
</span><br>
</div>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: `'\"var\"` messed quotes.

Comment: You should consider indenting your code, that's a mess. This could help you spot the error easily

Comment: 1. assign session and iterator variables to locals e.g. $part[\'partID\'] to a local $partID
2. divide and conquer - remove all code but variables and surround it with your code as required

Comment: Thanks you very much for all the feedback. I managed to get it working with your advice @user2648008>

Stever - My code was indented but after pasting it into the platform here I managed to muck it up a bit

u_mulder, I was not sure what you meant.